# R- Studio extracted function) works only with old col names

Tags: r, function, grouping, summarize

I have a large tibble with 300000 obs like this

```
          datetime            Temp
    <dbl> <dttm>              <dbl>
1   47650 2000-01-01 01:00:00  -3  
2   47650 2000-01-01 01:30:00  -3.1
3   47650 2000-01-01 02:00:00  -3.2
4   47650 2000-01-01 02:30:00  -3.1
5   47650 2000-01-01 03:00:00  -3.2
6   47650 2000-01-01 03:30:00  -3.4
```

to use only hourly mean values I use the following code:

```
df %>% group_by(datetime =format(datetime, '%Y-%m-%d %H') )%>%
   summarise ( Meanv = mean(col2,na.rm = TRUE))
```

this works nicely.
But if I extract this to a function (df,datetime,col2)
it does not work

I changed the parameters (input as characters); did not use the pipe; tried to unlist

```
df %>% group_by(datetime =format(datetime, '%Y-%m-%d %H') )%>%
   summarise ( Meanv = mean(col2,na.rm = TRUE))
```

> error in mean(WG, na.rm = TRUE) : Objekt 'Temp' not found

when df was changed to have colnames datetime & Temp as opoosed to datetime, col2 (the names where it worked)

Comment: *"extract this to a function"* is not telling enough of the story. If you're trying to do this operation inside a function, then it is likely that this is an issue with non-standard evaluation. If you're writing a function and it's failing, please post enough of the function. (Also, please use `dput(head(df))`: it's difficult to use this as-is due to the space in the `datetime` column, and you have an un-named column while missing `col2`. It's feasible for us to guess and fix it locally, but it'd be much easier if you posted the output of `dput`. Thanks!)

Answer (score 0):

Thank You for correcting my badly written input; (but I was not successful to do it better). 
In the meantime I found a better way to do it.
    `h_mean <- function(df){
              tb$b <- tb[[3]]
              tb$hour <- tb[[2]] %>% floor_date("hours")
              res <- tb %>% group_by(hour) %>% summaries(b = mean(b)
              return (res)
}`
This code works, the  first (after correcting my typo)  is still not working with the very large tibble. My Mac Book hangs up. And I would like to understand why

Comment: Sorry Part of the code was not pasted. Here ist th  head of the function:

Comment: ```h_mean <- function (tb) {.  # tb has three columns